# Eclipse - organizing field declarations

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing a desktop application using Google's WindowBuilderPro on Eclipse.

However, it generates a lot of codes like this:

```
protected JLabel lblNewLabel_2;
protected JLabel lblNewLabel_3;
protected JLabel lblNewLabel;
protected JLabel lblNewLabel_4;
protected JLabel lblNewLabel_5;
```

Is there anyway to organize it so that it all consolidates like this?

```
protected JLabel lblNewLabel_2, lblNewLabel_3, lblNewLabel, lblNewLabel_4, lblNewLabel_5;
```

The field declarations are taking about 100 lines alone...

Comment: Um, if the declarations are 100 lines or more.. do you really want to scroll all the way to the right? That will also get annoying.. this is where .NET regions would've been useful.

Comment: It's an accepted good practice to only put one declaration per line. I would rather ask myself if having 100 fields in a single class is a good idea. Shouldn't you split the class into several parts instead?

Comment: I see. I thought about consolidating them due to them looking messy and long... Guess I'll just have to deal with it.